# iOS Change Cell border tint color

Tags: ios, uitableview, colors

[image: My screenshot of my details view, need to change the colour with code and not storyboard]

The part of the cell that is orange, i did it with the storyboard, but i want to change it dynamically with the code. Anyone know what i need to change in my code to get it to work? I tried researching it, but no dice. Most of the colour changes i found were either for the background of the cell, the background for the table, the background for the text...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```